# Can't focus on EditText after setting focus to true

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

Im having trouble undestanding what is happening here.
If I don't mess with "setFocusable" on EditText it works like I excpect (when you click on it the keyboard pops up and you can edit it as normal), if I set it to true it also works like before:

```
holder.editTextExercise.setFocusable(true);
```

But if I set it to false, and than back to true, I can no longer see a keyboard pop up, so I can't edit it

```
    holder.editTextExercise.setFocusable(false);
    holder.editTextExercise.setFocusable(true);
```

Here is the EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recyclerExercise"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Im putting different items with EditTexts in the recycler and sometimes I want to change them so they can/can't be editable.
What is going on here?

Comment: its already been answered but if in case you need to use `.setFocusable(false);` , you can enable it again or " make the soft keyboard popup " by using `.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` on the same edittext whose focusable was set as false , additionally if you want to make the editext look disabled but do not want to disable it actually , you can use `.setAlpha(0.4f)` and `.setAlpha(1f)` when you want make it look enabled , THE advantage of using `.setFocusable(false);`  over `.setEnabled(false);` is that you can listen for clicks and touch for the edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
holder.editTextExercise.setFocusable(false);
holder.editTextExercise.setFocusable(true);
```

Try

```
holder.editTextExercise.setEnabled(false);
holder.editTextExercise.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Im just curious if you know why "setFocusable" does that?

Comment: Focusable is to set the focus and not to enable or disable the edittext that's why I suggested that. Please upvote my answer because this can help others as well.